# Unable to find "GoogleService-Info.plist" while trying to integrate Google Sign-in in my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-api, google-signin

I have followed : [Integrating Google Sign-In into your iOS app](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in)

However when I execute the app, it halts in the app delegate itself - even before I can see my first view controller.

The reason is because of these few lines of code I wrote in the `"application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions withOptions`", which are:

```
"NSError* configureError;
[[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError: &configureError];
    NSAssert(!configureError, @"Error configuring Google services: %@", configureError);

 [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;"
```

In the debug, when it reaches this code, it says

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error configuring Google
>   services: Error Domain=com.google.greenhouse Code=-200 "Unable to
>   configure GGL." UserInfo=0x7ff9c2e1d000
>   {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Check formatting and location of
>   GoogleService-Info.plist., NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to configure
>   GGL., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to parse supplied
>   GoogleService-Info.plist. See log for details.}'".

I put the `GoogleService-Info.plist` in my directory, but it still isn't working.

Comment: Welcome to stack:  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   It is ok to be frustrated but please keep your questions on topic in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I faced the same problem. And, actually, I solved it when in cocoapods file I placed "pod 'Google/SignIn'" instead of "pod Google". Hope it could help you too.

Comment: Bro Yeah - that was my problem too. Although, I found that out 2 weeks ago, still I am really grateful that there are such good Samaritans like you.

Comment: Hopefully, this thread will help someone else who has had such an issue.

Comment: As for me the file was not listed in "Copy Bundle Resources" in Build Phases. though I was getting the exact same error posted in OP (I'm using swift not Obj-C)

Answer (score 40):

1. You must drag and drop the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file into your project in a location such as `Shared Resources`. When you have successfully added the file, you should also make sure to include it in the project build:

[image: Image showing the added resource]

2. Double-check that in the "Build Phases" section of your project that your project is including `GoogleService-Info.plist`.
   [image]
3. Double check the file name. The file name **must** be exactly `GoogleService-Info.plist` common misspellings include *GoogleServices-Info.plist* and *GoogleService-info.plist* - case sensitive and exactly named only will work.

Comment: class, thanks a lot for your reply! , but my xcode project does not have a folder named "Shared Resources".

I added "GoogleService-Info.plist. " inside my target folder and it is inside the "Copy Bundle Resources" also, but it still showing the firetrucking error. :-(

Comment: Oh yeah - thought it my be useful to also tell you that the GoogleService-Info.plist. " is added into my target folder rather than the pods target (which I got after using cocoapods)

Comment: Is it included in the "copy bundle resources" section?

Comment: Thanks! Finally worked... even after painstakingly following google directions to the 'T'   still crashed... Google should add your info into their directions...

Comment: Hey I've tried drag & drop have the targets & also in build passes but it's still giving me the error. Can you help me? have a look on this question. I've followed above steps thoroughly I'm on Xcode 9.2

Comment: I couldn't see GoogleService-Info.plist in build phases how can i add them their

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna get only **GCM_SENDER_ID**, try this workaround:

```
NSError* configureError;
[[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError:&configureError];
NSString * gcmSenderID = [GGLContext sharedInstance].gcmSenderID;
NSLog(@"%@", gcmSenderID);
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me when I updated the google pods. They changed the way they configure URL schemes. The best way is to just reconfigure the google signin.

Answer (score 0):

For me..
I forgot to add the below pods. (cause i had some local issue before... so i removed all)

```
pod 'FirebaseUI/Auth'

pod 'FirebaseUI/Google'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Facebook'
pod 'FirebaseUI/OAuth' # Used for Sign in with Apple, Twitter, etc
pod 'FirebaseUI/Phone'
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui