# GCM : Configuring subspecs failed @ CloudMessaging

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to integrate Google Cloud Messaging in my iOS application. I have followed every instruction provided in [this link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client).

I have also integrated Google sign-in and it works fine.

The problem is I am getting assertion failure in the below code.

```
NSError* configureError;
[[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError:&configureError];
NSAssert(!configureError, @"Error configuring Google services: %@", configureError);
```

Which is used to configure subspecs for cloud messaging.
This code above is in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in `AppDelegate.m` file.

The error generated is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error configuring Google services: Error Domain=com.google.greenhouse Code=-104 "Unable to correctly configure subspec CloudMessaging" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to correctly configure subspec CloudMessaging, NSLocalizedFailureReason=GCM Sender ID must not be nil or empty.

Now I don't understand the meaning of this error. Yes, it clearly states that sender ID must not be nil. But from where it gets null ID.

I have tested this in simulator. I don't know if that affects or not.

If I comment this code and run in real device I also get the registration token but I don't receive any notification from my server. Server side code is tested and works fine for android.

Comment: FCM (previously GCM) cannot be tested on an emulator, you must use a real device. Also did you add the GoogleService-Info.plist into your project? Have a look here for setting up FCM on iOS: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

Comment: @ArthurThompson: Since they are using `GGLContext`, it looks like they are using GCM, not FCM.

Comment: Both GCM and FCM require a GoogleServices-info.plist it contains the required sender ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem. First of all thank you all for quick reply.
What I did is explained in the following steps.

1. Get GCMExample project. Which I downloaded from Github because `pod try google` does not list GCMExample project.
2. Generate GoogleServices-Info.plist file from [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client)
3. Compare plist files of GCMExample and MyProject.

Here I got the difference in it. In My project GCM was disabled and there was no Sender ID in it. I don't know how the hell did that happened. 
So I manually set the GCM service enabled and added sender ID of my app that I previously created.

That is how I solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Check Below Link for certificate

[cloud-messaging_ios_certs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/certs)

Make sure you are following below steps correctly

1. Create your App ID with Push Notifications ON.
2. Create your SSL Certificate.
3. Download and run it in order to be added to the Provisioning Profile.
4. To make sure that your provisioning profile has this certificate go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Account -> Your Apple ID -> Your Team -> View Details -> Download All.

Comment: How would I know if my provisioning profile contains the SSL (APNs Development iOS) certificate or not?

Comment: did you created certificate or apple id in apple developer portal?

Comment: Check this link https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/start you should implement applicationDidBecomeActive  like this                  -(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Connect to the GCM server to receive non-APNS notifications
    [[GCMService sharedInstance] connectWithHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Could not connect to GCM: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Connected to GCM");
            // ...
        }
    }];
}

Comment: I implemented that  method and other methods from the GCMExample too. But it still shows the same error.

Comment: check following link for multiple solution for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31294380/unable-to-find-googleservice-info-plist-while-trying-to-integrate-google-sign

Comment: Thanks but, I have already checked the link before posting this question. The one solution where we can log sender ID. I tried that and it logs null.

Comment: I got a SenderID while registration of the app on google. Do I have to set it somewhere or the configure will set it directly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113590/discussion-between-manan-devani-and-divyanshu-joshi).